# Using Flexbox with multiple Angular components

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular, flexbox

I'm currently trying to build a project using Angular, where I use Semantic-UI.

I'm trying to implement the following layout in my AppComponent, where my Header and Nav are different components, using flexbox:

[image: Layout]

My .html:

```
<div class="app">
  <div class="app-header">
    <ucecmp-header></ucecmp-header>
  </div>
  <div class="app-section">
    <div class="app-nav">
      <ucecmp-nav></ucecmp-nav>
    </div>
    <div class="app-content">
      <div class="ui huge header">Hello {{name}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my .css:

```
.app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.app-header {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.app-nav {
  flex: 0 0 250px;
  order: -1;
}

.app-section {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.app-content {
  flex: 1;
}
```

My problem is that I'm seeing my nav and content overlapping my header:

[image: My app shell]

I'm quite new to flexbox, so the problem might be obvious. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working with the following .css:

```
.app {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
}

.app-header {
  flex: 0 0 48px;
}

.app-nav {
  order: -1;
}

.app-section {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.app-content {
   flex: 1;
}
```